# Cython ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 3)

Tags: python, numpy, buffer, cython, valueerror

There are some similar questions, but none of them addresses my issue, so I am posting a new one here.

Cython is giving me an error when I try to give a function a 3-dimensional numpy array as input, telling me: "ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 3)". But when I give it a 2-dimensional array, it crashes (python stops responding, I think this is because I am trying to perform 3-dimensional matrix operations on a 2-dimensional array).

Then, I tried to typeset the input as a 3 dimensional array, but the function is still expecting a 2-dimensional array. I thought there might be something wrong with my code, but when I got rid of the cython variable declarations and ran it as a python file, everything was fine.

Here is the function declaration:

```
def isfc(np.ndarray[double, ndim=3] multi_activations, int gaussian_variance):
  #cython variable declaration
  cdef int time_len, activations_len, subj_num, timepoint, subj
  cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=2] correlations_vector, normalized_activations, coefficients,normalized_sum_activations
  cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=3] c_activations, activations_sum, correlations_mean
  cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=4] correlations
  cdef np.ndarray gaussian_array, coefficients_sum, coefficient, sigma_activations, sigma_activations_sum

  #assign initial parameters
  **subj_num, activations_len, time_len= multi_activations.shape[0],multi_activations.shape[1],multi_activations.shape[2]**
  coefficients_sum = np.zeros(time_len)
  correlations= np.zeros([subj_num, time_len,activations_len,activations_len])
  correlations_vector = np.zeros([time_len,(activations_len * (activations_len-1) / 2)])
  coefficients = np.zeros([time_len, activations_len,time_len])
  gaussian_array = np.array([exp(-timepoint**2/2/gaussian_variance)/sqrt(2*pi*gaussian_variance) for timepoint in range(-time_len+1,time_len)])
  **c_activations = np.array(multi_activations)**
```

The input in question is multi_activations, and it's only used on the lines marked with ** before it's copied to a 3-dimensional cython buffer.

I have narrowed down the error to be at the function call, specifically when I pass a 3-dimensional array to this function as the multi_activations input. I get an error at the function call, not within the function. It's simply a buffer size mismatch for the input parameter.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't use screenshots of your code. Post the code inline as text.

Comment: On top of that, show us *which* line the error happened on. Most helpful would be the full traceback of the error. You may benefit from [ask] and how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Please add the problematic code. For formatting of console output and code please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: What does 'it crashes' mean?  In one case you get ValueError.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about that. I have posted the code inline and marked out the code that are related to the problem. By "crashes", I mean an error message pops up saying "python has stopped responding". I think this is because, when I input a 2-dimensional array instead of a 3-dimensional array, my program is trying to do 3-dimensional cython operations on a 2-dimensional array which would lead to memory error

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs on the line:

```
coefficients = np.zeros([time_len, activations_len,time_len])
```

I get a helpful error message pointing to the right line. If you don't then it's probable that you've moved or renamed a file during the build process so it can't find the .pyx file when you run it.

The solution is either to change the type of `coefficients` to a 3D array, or to create a 2D array with `np.zeros`.

---

I can't reproduce your crash when passing it a 2D array - I just get a `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions`

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I don't know why the line number doesn't show up in the error. I don't think I moved my pyx file...